# How do I disable blood in Space Engineers?

Tags: space-engineers

I want to disable the blood particles in Space Engineers, but I don't see a way do to so in the options. Am I missing something or do I have to do something in the game files?

I've tried removing and replacing the blood textures in Content/Textures/Particles
but the game seems to still show the correct textures.